# System.Xml.Xpath not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xpath, compact-framework, system.xml

I tried to include System.Xml.Xpath in C#.NET to do wp7 programs  for parsing XML. I have added the reference System.Xml but Xpath is not found.

Comment: WP7 has a restricted subset of the BCL libraries, in order to conserve space and memory. This is one of those that is excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no System.Xml.Xpath support in Windows Phone, you'll have to use an external assembly that does support XPath, or use Linq to XML (quite recommended!)